# Did the Soviet Union or China participate in the light bulb cartel? If not, in what ways did they differ and how long did their bulbs last?

Tags: soviet-union, china, technology, cold-war, historical-techniques

The [Phoebus cartel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoebus_cartel) was a well known scheme to fix the standard lifespan of incandescent lightbulbs that arose at the beginning of the 20th century.
[See Spectrum.ieee.org](https://spectrum.ieee.org/the-great-lightbulb-conspiracy).

Although not implemented for entirely nefarious purposes, there certainly was a motivating aspect that would likely have been resisted by the Soviet Union and China given their political positions.

Was there ever an on the record policy or standard that gave rise to a different type of, presumably longer lasting, light bulb?

And if so, has anyone ever investigated and compared these light bulbs?

Comment: Certainly customers would have been able to compare lightbulbs, e.g. across the East German/ West German border or all across the Warsaw pact pre- vs. post-1990. I personally never heard that it made any difference. For East Germany, things usually mentioned re. cross-border shopping in the East are foodstuffs (by East Germans and official propaganda) and books (by West Germans). Never heard much about light bulbs.

Comment: I guess one could compare annual lightbulb production (minus export) to the number of rooms per family to get a first reasonable estimate.

Comment: Why would they? What possible motivation would they have to do so?  I'm curious to know if there were any trade in light bulbs across the iron curtain- how would they have paid for the trade?  Soviet demand for goods exceeded production; intentional obsolescence would be quite counterproductive.  I don't see how ideological constraints enter into this. I haven't researched this, but my starting hypothesis would be that they didn't participate because total light bulb trade was 0 dollars/0 rubles.

Comment: @Jan ~1989 it was told that Osram vs Narva: 750h vs 1500h? These are numbers from newspapers, no real hard comparisons though. GDR lightbulbs, then East-German lightbulbs were & _are_ advertised as 'longer lasting' (old GDR stuff & "are": on ebay, i case you wondered…). And that ad-angle is for household items in general, fridges etc.

Comment: @MCW export of East German household electrics across the iron curtain to the west was common. Payment was in hard currency. Certain internet forums claim this also applied to NARVA light bulbs, but I was unable to find something more reliable.

Comment: @LangLangC interesting. According to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoebus_cartel) wp article, it seems there is a trade-off between brightness, energy consumption and longevity of a light bulb, and it would be somewhat logical for East Germany to optimize for higher longevity.

Comment: But the question asks about Soviet/Chinese, not East German.  I know there was _some_ integration of E. German and Soviet economies, but I don't know how much.

Comment: @MCW Indeed, the Comecon economy was to a large degree coordinated. And not just East German but also quite explicitly Hungarian bulbs were said to last longer as well. Trade-offs in optimisation of target points did/does play a role, but others as well, and the cartel was (imo) not just about 1000h-max, but mainly a _regional_ monopoly, ie: price fixing. Problem here: dozens of articles claiming these anecdotes, but no hard numbers or objective comparison I ever found. And this is about a _'documented decision_ in eg SU', not even effective observed outcome.

Comment: I'm noticing a lot of anachronistic comments here that don't seem to realize that the cartel in question ended in 1939 with the start of WWII. The question itself seems to suffer from the same problem, as the end of the cartel also predates the People's Republic of China.

Comment: @T.E.D. The cartel is said to have _operated_ until at least 1942, its _effects_ are said to to have lasted until today. So, you may be right _for the official cartel phase,_ 'Red' China in Q might already be anachronistic?

Comment: Could you clarify the criticism apparent down in comments here about the timeframe and how it might affect _your_ USSR/'China' angle? The official cartel phase pretty much was over before Mao took over, the 'conspiracy' phase effected the market longer (ie 'the standard' of effectively 1000hmax). But still the 'members of the cartel from 1924' are known and listed. So please clarify with an [edit] how this info and your own preliminary research could describe the problem with more precision.

Comment: I do not see any reasons to expect that self-described socialist countries would participate in a capitalist cartel. Still, the question about efficiency of their light bulbs does make sense.